# Find duplicate row record and update another column

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have the following table:

```
Destination     Last Result
(555) 319-5170  Disconnect
(555) 319-5170  Duplicate
(555) 319-5170  Duplicate
(555) 261-5000  Duplicate
(555) 261-5000  Duplicate
(555) 261-7325  Busy
(555) 261-7325  Duplicate
```

I would like to find all duplicate `Destination(Phone numbers)` and update the 'Last Result' column for all matching phone numbers with a value that is not equal to 'Duplicate'. So, in the example table above for Destination((555) 319-5170), the result for all matching phone numbers(555) 319-5170) with the value 'Disconnect'. My query is below, but I am getting an error.

```
update Call
set [last result] = (
select [last result] 
from Call
 WHERE Destination in (select destination from Call group by destination having count(*)>1) and [Last result] != 'Duplicate' and [Last result] != 'No Phone #')
 WHERE Destination in (select destination from Call group by destination having count(*)>1) and [Last result] != 'Duplicate' and [Last result] != 'No Phone #'

Destination     Last Result - EXPECTED OUTPUT
(555) 319-5170  Disconnect
(555) 319-5170  Disconnect
(555) 319-5170  Disconnect
(555) 261-5000  Duplicate
(555) 261-5000  Duplicate
(555) 261-7325  Busy
(555) 261-7325  Busy
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance with a possible solution.

Comment: what rdbms are you using? What is the error message?

Comment: Can you show expected results and tag DBMS name?

Comment: DBMS is SQL Server 2008.@bluefeet

Comment: (555) 319-5170  Disconnect
(555) 319-5170  Disconnect
(555) 319-5170  Disconnect
(555) 261-5000  Duplicate
(555) 261-5000  Duplicate
(555) 261-7325  Busy
(555) 261-7325  Busy @Kaf

Answer (score 0):

Your sub query is returning more than one result which is why you are getting an exception.

This query should work for you instead (if i've understood your criteria correctly):

```
UPDATE C
SET [Last Result] = 'Disconnect'
FROM Call C
INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Destination
            FROM Call
            WHERE [Last Result] NOT IN ('Duplicate','No Phone #')
            GROUP BY Destination
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) Dup ON Dup.Destination = C.Destination
WHERE C.[Last Result] NOT IN ('Duplicate','No Phone #')
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!! I have one additional questions.. Instead of setting a "static" value for the duplicate destinations(Phone numbers), how would I dynamically assign duplicate phone numbers the value in [Last Result] that is not equal to 'Duplicate' I hope I did not over complicate the request.

Comment: @user2051135 It depends on how you want it to work. What is the criteria for dynamically assigning the values to [Last Resort]? Could you update the original post with an example. Thanks.

Comment: The criteria for dynamically assigning the values to [Last Resort] will include capturing the value for matching phone numbers. 
Example: 
(555) 261-7325  Busy
(555) 261-7325  Duplicate

In the above case, the [Last Resort] would be assigned "Busy" for all phone numbers((555) 261-7325) matching.

Output woud then be:
(555) 261-7325  Busy
(555) 261-7325  Busy @JBond312

Answer (score 0):

I am making a small change to JBond312's answer,

```
UPDATE C
SET [Last Result] = 'Disconnect'
FROM Call C
INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Destination
            FROM Call
            WHERE [Last Result] NOT IN ('Duplicate','No Phone #')
            GROUP BY Destination
            HAVING COUNT(Destination) > 1
        ) Dup ON Dup.Destination = C.Destination
WHERE C.[Last Result] NOT IN ('Duplicate','No Phone #')
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!! I have one additional questions.. Instead of setting a "static" value for the duplicate destinations(Phone numbers), how would I dynamically assign duplicate phone numbers the value in [Last Result] that is not equal to 'Duplicate' I hope I did not over complicate the request. @Ankit

Comment: Please support with example.. I am unable understand your requirement

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The criteria for dynamically assigning the values to [Last Result] include capturing the value[last result] for all matching phone numbers and then updating all values with a value that is not equal to "duplicate". Example: (555) 261-7325 Busy (555) 261-7325 Duplicate In the above case, the [Last Resort] would be assigned "Busy" for all phone numbers((555) 261-7325) matching. Output would then be: (555) 261-7325 Busy (555) 261-7325 Busy

Comment: still not clear.. can you please update your question and show a dummy table and required output...

Comment: I updated the original question and hope it is more clear. Thanks again. @Ankit

Comment: I was able to resolve my problem using the following:  <pre>update  t1
set     [Last Result] = t2.[Last Result]
from    Table1 t1
join    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by Destination
                                   order by Id) as rn
        ,        *
        from     Table1
        ) t2
on      t1.Destination = t2.Destination
        and t2.rn = 1;</pre>